# PHP + mysql - inserir basedados mysql todos nome ficheiro e o caminho

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

estou a trabalhar num php em localhost onde a partir da pasta root será para ler todos os ficheiros e pastas e inserir numa basedados MYSQL
mas estou a ter dificuldades
alguem pode ajudar?
obrgd ;)

```
/*CONNECT DB */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "beifaserver") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));


mysqli_query($link,"delete from search"); 
/*CLEAN DB TABLE*/


function listFolderFiles($dir){  /*READ DIR/ File*/
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '';
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                echo $ff;
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);

            }
            else{
                echo ''.$ff.'';
                $try = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO search (title,url, dategrab)VALUES ('".$ff."', '".$dir."/".$ff."', '".date('2004-m-d H:i:s')."')");
                    if($try === false){
                    echo 'error - ';
                    echo mysqli_error($link);
                }
            }
            echo '';
        }
    }
    echo '';
}


listFolderFiles('../');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### O código

Eu refiz todo o código, porém orientado a objetos e utilizando PDO (PHP Data Object) eu testei o código e está funcionando perfeitamente. Como usei os dados de seu banco de dados basta rodar o código. Eu também mudei o nome da função para `fromFolderToDB`.

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:server=localhost;dbname=beifaserver', 'root', 'usbw');
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

function fromFolderToDB ($path) {
    global $pdo;

    foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file ) {
        if ( !$file->isDot() ) {
            $date = new DateTime();

            $fileName = $file->getFileName();
            $filePath = $path . $fileName;
            $dateGrab = $date->format('2004-m-d H:i:s');

            $sth = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `search` (`title`, `url`, `dategrab`) VALUES ('${fileName}', '${filePath}', '${dateGrab}')");
            $sth->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

### Exemplos

Se você deseja, por exemplo, adicionar todos os arquivos do diretório css basta executar o seguinte código:

```
fromFolderToDB('css');
```

Qualquer dúvida informe pelos comentários.

Comment: por enquanto da o seguinte erro: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Nenhuma ligação pôde ser feita porque o computador de destino as recusou ativamente.

Comment: tenho um que deu mas nao tem o caminho url so mostra ficheiro:

Comment: Esse erro (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]) ocorre porque o MySQL não está ativado. Se você usa Xampp é só ir no Control Panel e ativá-lo.